# spring roo backup command lost my files

Tags: spring, backup, recovery, spring-roo

I generated spring roo project and modifies .jspx files to my styles.  Unfortunately, when i used the backup command, spring roo was auto-generated files to the original one.  Thus, my .jspx files are noy my styles.  How should i do to recovery my files back from this command.

Answer (score 1):

Check the comment in this [JIRA-Issue about "Adding field overwrites changes in *.jspx"](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-552). By default, the automatically created views (.jspx) are maintained by Roo. You can

- turn this off by setting "automaticallyMaintainView = false" and edit everything freely (of course, there will be no changes made to the views anymore if you add a field to an entity)
- use your own jspx files that Roo doesn't even know about
- wait until
  Roo 1.1 in which the Roo support for
  views is moving to the element level (as I understand it),
  see [this issue where it is explained
  in the comments](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-612). I think this will allow for .jspx files which are partly user- and partly roo-managed.